# how to Insert , overwrite audio files -Audio Editing iphone

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0

I am developing an application which does audio recording. Now I need to add a feature of editing the recorded audio file... The user should be able to play the audio file & insert recording into that.. cut unwanted audio .. I need the two basic functionality INSERT audio & overwrite existing audio.

Is there any inbuilt function? Any useful link related to this will be helpful

Comment: pradeep can you kindly give me some hints for audio recording in iphone?

Comment: Hello Pradeep, I am also in a need of same... did u find anything ?
if yes, please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did anyone ever solve this Audio editing? Please share the code!

Comment: Hi, I am also need this kind of solution, if you have any samples means kindly share me, because i am in critical situation,please help me