# how to insert and overwrite audio file in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, core-audio

Am developing an application which has audio recorder. The user should be able to play the audio file & insert recording into that.. cut unwanted audio .. overwrite some part of audio file.

Have you seen [how to Insert , overwrite audio files -Audio Editing iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584035/how-to-insert-overwrite-audio-files-audio-editing-iphone)? but no one answered this...

Atleast suggest me a way to implement this....

Thanx in advance...

Comment: Can you provide me with the links where to start... I have done voice recorder but I cant move up with insert or overwrite features...

Comment: arvind can u found solution for this? How to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What type of audio file are you talking about?  You will almost certainly need to convert whatever you are using into PCM WAV data for this type of manipulation.  Luckily, Core Audio, which others have pointed you towards has some convenience methods for doing this.

Once you have the raw PCM data, you can insert by simply inserting other PCM data at the desired point in the data.  You want to make sure you don't do something like write in the middle of a stereo packet, or something like that, but besides that, most simply-formatted PCM data is pretty easy to manipulate.  Think of it like a string -- you can start with "Hello World" and change it to "Hello, Beautiful World" but simply inserting data in the middle.

Overwriting is the same principal.

Once you are done with the edits, you'll need to transform the PCM data back into whatever format you had saved in before.

Comment: Do you have code examples of these convenience methods? Haven't been able to find anything like this

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Core Audio](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/CoreAudioOverview/Introduction/Introduction.html)

> Core Audio provides software interfaces for implementing audio features in applications you create for iOS and OS X. Under the hood, it handles all aspects of audio on each of these platforms. In iOS, Core Audio capabilities include recording, playback, sound effects, positioning, format conversion, and file stream parsing, as well as:

Comment: this is the most generic answer you possibly could have given.

Comment: It was a very generic question.